# Does jQuery ship with SharePoint?

Tags: jquery

Currently, we want to upgrade jQuery in our products, so I want to know if SharePoint use jquery in its js? It will help us to make decision about which jquery version we are going to use. I try to find jquery reference in SharePoint 2010, but I didn't find it. Does it mean there is no jQuery in SharePoint?

I found there is a js called "mQuery.js" in SharePoint 2013, the usage is quite similar with jQuery, and even most of the events'name are same. Why does Microsoft create a js for SharePoint 2013 instead of using jQuery directly? Because some functions in jQuery are unnecessary? Or for easy maintenance?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 there is no JQuery by default. So basically SharePoint uses just JavaScript etc.

If you want to use JQuery in your own solutions or some client side programmint etc, you normally have to register the JQuery library in the master page.

Hope it helps

Comment: Look out if you use jQuery in SharePoint 2010 because the SP javascript contains the "$", so using $('#id') could give you the wrong code. To solve this, use instead jQuery('#id') or place jQuery.noConflict(); at the start of your script

Comment: `(function($){...})(jQuery);`

Comment: There are only a few small places where you run into the conflict mentioned by Ruben above. Image Library pages is one and there is one other which I can't recall at the moment. Otherwise, you'll be fine.